# Docker doesn't save the network i create

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I want to create a network in docker, i use this two ways:

1.- `sudo docker network create -d overlay --subnet=192.168.57.0/24 --gateway=192.168.57.1 overlaydefinitivo2`
However, after i create this network, if i use `docker network inspect overlaydefinitivo2` the output is the following one:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "overlaydefinitivo2",
        "Id": "mkv1jy6f1v2h3i04ss64rgn1k",
        "Created": "2022-05-21T00:30:14.928276148Z",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": null
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": null,
        "Options": null,
        "Labels": null
    }
]
```

As you can see, it doesn't save the IP address, gateway and the driver i used.

The other way i'm trying to create my network is the following one:

```
networks:
 pepito:
 driver: overlay
 config:
  - subnet="192.168.57.0/24"
  - gateway="192.168.57.1"
```

However, when i try to use `sudo docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml phpmyadmin123` it gets the following output:

```
networks.config must be a mapping or null
```

I don't know what i did wrong in the two ways i'm making the network, i already checked the yml indentation and it seems ok.

Thanks for your time.

`

Comment: The CLI command should work as well. Do you have a running swarm (you'll find the networks `ingress` and `docker_gwbridge` in `docker network ls` then). Else do `docker swarm init`first. And did you made sure there is no overlap with other networks in this IP range?

Comment: What does `docker node inspect self` say? (You may delete the certificate keys in `TLSInfo`, but they have to be there..). Did you remove the network from manager (and maybe workers) before trying to create a new one? What does `docker info` says in the `Swarm:` part? (all indented key/value)

Answer (score 0):

fix your indentation and you'll not get that error

```
networks:
  pepito:
    driver: overlay
    config:
      - subnet="192.168.57.0/24"
      - gateway="192.168.57.1"
```